# Kivy texture remains black

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have a camera which produces ushort grayscale images, which can be displayed with e.g. matplotlib. I want to display the video of the camera with Kivy using the following code, but I only get a black display. What do I do wrong?

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
import cv2
import TTCamera

SIZE = 1288, 968


class Test(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cam = TTCamera.Camera()
        (im, _) = self.cam.takeImage(0.001, 0, 2)
        texture = Texture.create(size=(SIZE[0], SIZE[1]), colorfmt='luminance')
        texture.blit_buffer(im.flatten(), colorfmt='luminance', bufferfmt='ushort')

        with self.canvas:
            Rectangle(texture=texture, pos=self.pos, size=(SIZE[0], SIZE[1]))


class DemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it seems to work, but the image was too dark to see any details in it.